Mathematically solving for the energy loss in a resistor with ramping voltage over time
I am trying to calculate the total energy in a resistor where a constant voltage ramp is applied over time t. I am a little rusty on how to set it up.
We know energy is power multiplied with time or E = P * t. And for a resistor P = V^2 / R
So we should end up with
$$
E= \frac{V^2}{R}t
$$
But we are ramping the voltage from 0 to Vmax in time 0 to t (linear ramp). My final values are Vmax=90.000 Volts and t=4 milliseconds.
I tried to set this up and solve as a double integral. Initially when i set it up i did it wrong as
$$
E= \int{\int{}}\frac{V^2}{R}t*dv*dt
$$
I get wildly wrong result.
I think i should convert the variables to dX to start with such as
$$
E= \int{\int{}}\frac{(dV)^2}{R}*dT
$$
But i am now not sure how to proceed with the squared dV. How do we proceed step wise with this that will yield the correct result?

Try expressing the voltage as a constant ramp rate multiplied by the time. Calculate the corresponding energy dissipation for any one moment, and then integrate that over time. There’s no need for a double integral.

With ramping you mean $V(t)=a\cdot t$ ? so you have to integrate over $V^2(t)/R dt$ over the period of the ramping.

This was what was needed.
